# How to display number of lines in a file python

Tags: python

I assume that I have a text file which contains many lines for example:

```
fsdfgsfgf
b3cbc3b45
456346aaa
bce45fa45
```

I want to display each line and it number:

```
text_file = open(r'C:\\Users\\user\\Text.txt', 'r')
for a in Plaintxt_file:
    text=a[0:9]
    print ('Text:', text )
    print('it is number is:', a)
```

The result that I want is:

```
Text: b3cbc3b45
it is number is:2
```

But What I have as a result is:

```
Text: b3cbc3b45
it is number is:b3cbc3b45
```

So how to display the number of a file's line in python ?

Comment: Because your text variable is accessing the indexes of the file lines, not the line number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# with open(filename) as file:
#     for index, line in enumerate(file,1)
file = ['fsdfgsfgf','b3cbc3b45','456346aaa','bce45fa45']
for index, line in enumerate(file,1):
    print ('Text:', line )
    print('it is number is:', index)
```

out:

```
Text: fsdfgsfgf
it is number is: 1
Text: b3cbc3b45
it is number is: 2
Text: 456346aaa
it is number is: 3
Text: bce45fa45
it is number is: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `enumerate` command with the `readlines()` method like this:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
     # index represents the index of the line and line the line in the file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `with` to open file, `enumerate` to show the line number.

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        print 'Text:', line,
        print 'Its number is:', index
```